# MySQL Multiple Joins Causing Both Columns to Change

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database for managing sales at a store. I’m trying to write a query that gets the total cost for each invoice and the total amount paid.

All payments are recorded in the ‘invoice_payments’ table. The total cost for an invoice is the job_price + all stock_unit items (products).

**‘invoice’ Table**:

```
invoice_id  job_price
000071      100.00
```

**‘stock_unit’ Table**:

```
unit_id     price       invoice_id
000261      10      000071
000262      10      000071
000263      10      000071
```

**‘invoice_payments’ Table**:

```
payment_id  invoice_id  amount
000074      000071      100.00
000075      000071      30.00
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT
    invoice.invoice_id, 
    SUM(stock_unit.`sold_price` + invoice.job_price) AS price,
    SUM(`invoice_payments`.`amount`) AS paid

FROM invoice

LEFT JOIN stock_unit
    ON stock_unit.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id

LEFT JOIN invoice_payments
    ON invoice_payments.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id

GROUP BY invoice.invoice_id
```

The query works as expected when there is only 1 join, but when 2 are added they affect each other.

**Before I add the ‘invoice_payments’ join**:

```
invoice_id  paid
000071      130.00
```

**After**:

```
invoice_id  price       paid
000071      660.00      390.00
```

**What it should be**:

```
invoice_id  price       paid
000071      130.00      130.00
```

SQL Fiddle isn't working correctly but I've put a schema here so you can get a better idea for my table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/091a35

Am I better to have 3 seperate queries and join those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Samantha from Codecademy for solving this!

The first join returns multiple rows for each invoice. The amount depends on how many payments you have.

When the second join is executed it's trying to join onto the multiple results of the first invoice which means it's matching multiple times on a single invoice.

To fix this we use subqueries to group the first join then join the condensed results to the next query.

**Example:**

```
SELECT sub.invoice_id, sub.price, SUM(invoice_payments.amount) AS paid FROM

    (SELECT
        invoice.invoice_id AS invoice_id,
        SUM(stock_unit.sold_price) + invoice.job_price AS price
    FROM invoice

    LEFT JOIN stock_unit
        ON stock_unit.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id

    GROUP BY invoice.invoice_id) AS sub

LEFT JOIN invoice_payments
    ON invoice_payments.invoice_id = sub.invoice_id

GROUP BY sub.invoice_id;
```

**This also works:**

```
SELECT invoice_payments.invoice_id, p.price, SUM(invoice_payments.amount) AS paid
    FROM invoice_payments JOIN
        (select stock_unit.invoice_id, SUM(sold_price) + invoice.job_price AS price FROM stock_unit join
            invoice ON invoice.invoice_id=stock_unit.invoice_id) AS p
        ON p.invoice_id = invoice_payments.invoice_id GROUP BY invoice_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select e separated  result and not calculate the result od both is the same query joined

```
SELECT t1.invoce_id, t1.price, t2.paid FROM 

( 
SELECT     
     invoice.invoice_id AS invoce_id, 
    SUM(stock_unit.`sold_price` + invoice.job_price) AS price
FROM invoice
LEFT JOIN stock_unit
    ON stock_unit.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
GROUP BY invoice.invoice_id ) AS t1

LEFT JOIN 

(
SELECT 
    invoice.invoice_id AS invoce_id, 
    SUM(`invoice_payments`.`amount`) AS paid
FROM invoice    
LEFT JOIN invoice_payments
    ON invoice_payments.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
GROUP BY invoice.invoice_id ) AS t2 

ON t1.invoce_id = t2.invoce_id
```

Comment: This is still producing the same unexpected results.

Comment: Removing one of the joins still produces the correct results but having both causes the issue. I've added a schema in an SQL Fiddle to the original post.

Comment: @JacobWood  I don'y undestand,   the sqlfiddle wih my selcet   return  71, 330 ,130   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/091a35/2 not 000071  ,    660.00   ,   390.00 like in your question